# Append to certain line of file with awk, leaving non-matching lines unchanged

Tags: linux, awk, text-processing

given file *test* and its content:

```
bcd://dfl
sf
```

I would like to append *extra information* to the line having certain content (starting with *bcd*)
While the following script works

```
awk '/bcd*/ {print $0", extra information"} ' test > test.old && mv test.old test
```

it removes the non matching lines. (*sf*)

Is it possible to preserve them in the output file?

Comment: Append `", extra information"` to `$0` and output with `1`after `}`. Also fix that `/bcd*/`, it matches any string with `bc` in it. You probably meant `/^bcd.*/` but `/^bcd/` suffices.

Comment: Add `next` to the action block and add something of truth to cause printing after to default print: `awk '/^bcd/ {print $0", extra information"; next} 1'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *discussed* over in the comments appending a `{..}1` at the end will solve your problem,

```
awk '/^bcd/ {print $0", extra information"; next} 1' file
```

because the  `/<pattern>/{<action>}` is applied to the lines *only* matching the `<pattern>`, the other lines are just printed as-is, `{..}1` is a *always-true-no-matter-what* condition to print lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/^bcd/ {$0 = $0 ", extra information"} 1' test
```